# Insert continuous number from 1-100 PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hello so I have a table named tbl_value and have 2 columns (id, number) and what I want to do is run a query that inserts 1-100 rows. My code for now is

```
$stmt = $dbc->query("INSERT INTO tbl_inc (number) VALUES ('1')");
$stmt = $dbc->query("INSERT INTO tbl_inc (number) VALUES ('2')");
$stmt = $dbc->query("INSERT INTO tbl_inc (number) VALUES ('3')");
```

so forth and so on up to 100. How can I run a single query (no loop) that inserts 1-100? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean a bulk insert, or a loop which makes the insert a 100 times?

Comment: run a for loop `for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++) {  $stmt = $dbc->query("INSERT INTO tbl_inc (number) VALUES ('".$i."')"); }`

Comment: Note : "Single query" to do this job ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Without loop:**

```
<?php

$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_inc (number) VALUES ('";
$vals = range(1, 100);
$sql .= implode( "') , ('" , $vals)."')";
$stmt = $dbc->query($sql);

?>
```

**Output :**

```
INSERT INTO tbl_inc (number) VALUES ('1') , ('2') , ('3') , ('4') , ('5') , ('6') , ('7') , ('8') , ('9') , ('10') , ('11') , ('12') , ('13') , ('14') , ('15') , ('16') , ('17') , ('18') , ('19') , ('20') , ('21') , ('22') , ('23') , ('24') , ('25') , ('26') , ('27') , ('28') , ('29') , ('30') , ('31') , ('32') , ('33') , ('34') , ('35') , ('36') , ('37') , ('38') , ('39') , ('40') , ('41') , ('42') , ('43') , ('44') , ('45') , ('46') , ('47') , ('48') , ('49') , ('50') , ('51') , ('52') , ('53') , ('54') , ('55') , ('56') , ('57') , ('58') , ('59') , ('60') , ('61') , ('62') , ('63') , ('64') , ('65') , ('66') , ('67') , ('68') , ('69') , ('70') , ('71') , ('72') , ('73') , ('74') , ('75') , ('76') , ('77') , ('78') , ('79') , ('80') , ('81') , ('82') , ('83') , ('84') , ('85') , ('86') , ('87') , ('88') , ('89') , ('90') , ('91') , ('92') , ('93') , ('94') , ('95') , ('96') , ('97') , ('98') , ('99') , ('100')
```

Comment: Will give this a plus because no loop used.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a loop and generate the query. Try this -

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_inc (number) VALUES ";
$vals = array();
for($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i ++) {
   $vals[] = "('$i')";
}
$sql .= implode(',', $vals);
$stmt = $dbc->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

Fastest solution is to create a flat file and `LOAD DATA INFILE` make sure to check permissions.

```
$fp = fopen('/mylocation/mytext.txt', "a+");

for($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++){
  fwrite($fp, $i."\n");
}

fclose($fp);

$sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE /mylocation/mytext.txt
        INTO TABLE mytbl
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'";
$stmt = $dbc->query($sql);

unlink('/mylocation/mytext.txt');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i = 1; $i<= 100; $i++) {
     $dbc->query("INSERT INTO tbl_inc (number) VALUES (".$i.")");
}
```

Try above code

Comment: @FewFlyBy note that this is not a single query. He is executing a new query for every number.